# Finding conditional probability of a specific problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have this problem which I can't figure out how to solve. I was wondering if my thought process is right or wrong. Some tips would be helpful!

> Jen will call Cathy on Saturday with a 60% probability. She will call
> Cathy on Sunday with an 80% probability. The probability that she will call on
> neither of the two days is 10%. What is the probability that she will call on Sunday
> if she calls on Saturday?

This is a problem from [Fundamentals of Probability: A First Course
By Anirban DasGupta](https://books.google.am/books?id=uTtDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=Jen%20will%20call%20Cathy%20on%20Saturday%20with%20a%2060%25%20probability.%20She%20will%20call%20Cathy%20on%20Sunday%20with%20an%2080%25%20probability.%20The%20probability%20that%20she%20will%20call%20on%20neither%20of%20the%20two%20days%20is%2010%25.%20What%20is%20the%20probability%20that%20she%20will%20call%20on%20Sunday%20if%20she%20calls%20on%20Saturday?&source=bl&ots=F5xzLXcXIT&sig=ACfU3U1HXbTyA8oxXlh2xKoDyBYDHkXnTg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz5JWL8-uBAxXbSvEDHREWAG8Q6AF6BAgNEAM#v=onepage&q=Jen%20will%20call%20Cathy%20on%20Saturday%20with%20a%2060%25%20probability.%20She%20will%20call%20Cathy%20on%20Sunday%20with%20an%2080%25%20probability.%20The%20probability%20that%20she%20will%20call%20on%20neither%20of%20the%20two%20days%20is%2010%25.%20What%20is%20the%20probability%20that%20she%20will%20call%20on%20Sunday%20if%20she%20calls%20on%20Saturday%3F&f=false) (page 39 problem 3.2)

So I think we can use the hierarchical multiplicative formula.

> $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \ ...\ \cap A_k) = P(A_1) P(A_2\mid A_1) P(A_3 \mid A_1 \cap A_2) \times ... \times P(A_k \mid A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_{k-1})$>

For k = 3 and $A_1$ = {the probability that she will ring (which is 0.9)} $A_2$ = the probability that she will ring on Saturday and  $A_3$  = the probability that she will call on Sunday we will have $ 0.8 \times 0.6 =0.9 \times 0.6 \times x $
where $x = P(A_3 \mid A_1 \cap A_2) = \frac{8}{9}$
I know my deductions are wrong, but I can't figure out which parts and how to solve this the right way.

The answer is 5/6, according to my knowledge (source:  [here](https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2017/fs/401-2604-00L/ex/hints_DasGupta.pdf)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $A$ the event that she calls on saturday and $B$ the event that she calls on sunday.

Then the problem is asking for $P(B | A)$, which by definition is: $$P(B | A) = \frac{P(B \cap A) }{ P(A)}.$$

The problem also gives you the values of

- $P(A)$;
- $P(B)$;
- $P(\bar A \cap \bar B)$.

Then you can use:

- the value of $P(\bar A \cap \bar B)$ to deduce $P(A \cup B)$;
- the values of $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A \cup B)$ to deduce $P(A \cap B)$.

I confirm that the final answer is $P(B | A) = 5/6$.

Comment: But the 2 events don't depend on one another, right? 
The only dependence here is between calling and calling on Saturday, or calling (0.9) and calling on Sunday as I understand.

Comment: @HH How do you know that the two events don't depend on one another? That's not a hypothesis of the problem. Jen is a human being, we have no reason to assume that the event "Jen calls Cathy on sunday" is independent from the event "Jen calls Cathy on sunday".

Comment: @HH Saying tha the two events are independent is the same as saying that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ (that's the mathematical definition of independence of two events) and in this case it's false, $P(A \cap B) = 0.5$ and $P(A)P(B) = 12/25$. Alternatively, the two events are independent if $P(B | A) = P(B)$, which is false in retrospect, since $P(B) = 0.8$ but $P(B | A) = 5/6 \approx 0.87$.

Comment: Finally got that. Thank you so much!!! 
So my initial assumption was wrong about the independence of the decisions.

Comment: @HH Note that if the problem had been instead *"Jen will call Cathy on Saturday with a 60% probability. She will call Cathy on Sunday with an 80% probability. **These two events are independent.** What is the probability that she will call on Sunday if she calls on Saturday?"* Then you could have answered "80%" without any calculation. But note that to add hypothesis "these two events are independent" to the problem, I had to remove "the probability that she calls neither saturday nor sunday is 10%" because the two hypotheses together would be inconsistent.

Comment: I got that,  but if it said that they are independent and also said that "the probability that she calls neither Saturday nor Sunday is 10%" would the problem be unsolvable then?

Comment: @HH It's not that it would be insolvable, it's that the hypotheses would lead to a contradiction. Using the fact that $P(\bar A \cap \bar B) = 10\%$ you could prove that $P(B \mid A) = 5/6$, and using the fact that the two events are independent you could prove that $P(B \mid A) = 80\%$, and using the two together you could prove that $5/6 = 80\%$, or equivalently that $2+2 = 5$. When you start with a set of hypotheses and arrive at a contradiction, the logical conclusion is "at least one of the hypotheses is false".

Comment: Thank you very much!